# node.js cannot find module when running babel script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When running my dev script in i get an error to the directory of my project. I am assuming this is due to babel transpiling, but am not sure what else to do to debug this problem. I have removed and reinstall my node modules, restarted my servers, and made sure babel-node is located within the node_modules directory. I do not understand why an error is being thrown on the project directory.
My project structure looks like:

```
/server
 - package.json
 - /node_modules
 - /src
    - server.js
    - /routes
    - /models
    - /controllers
    - /etc....
```

The error thrown when running `yarn dev`

```
➜ yarn dev
yarn run v1.5.1
$ nodemon -w src --exec "babel-node src --presets env,stage-0"
[nodemon] 1.17.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /Users/altrock/Desktop/work/app/server/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src --presets env,stage-0`
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/altrock/Desktop/work/app/server/src'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/altrock/Desktop/work/app/server/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

package.json with dev script and dependencies

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src --exec \"babel-node src --presets env,stage-0\"",
    "build": "babel src -s -D -d dist --presets env,stage-0",
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "archiver": "^2.1.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem myself, where any `npm` or `node` command resulted in a module not found. If it is your last resort, reinstall node.js and npm, it worked for me.

Comment: '/Users/altrock/Desktop/work/app/server/src'  am not sure if nodejs is case sensitive but the server in your provided directory is Server not server

Comment: @Mowzey ah i actually typed it wrong. the directory is lowercase. i've fixed it in my post.

Comment: okay yes but now you see the error is still pointing to a directory not a module in there like server.js

Comment: How are you including the module?

Comment: @Mowzey yes, that is one thing i do not understand. why is it not pointing to a specfic file or module?

Comment: @Mowzey the src folder contains all my server files. the dev script watches those files and transpiles them with babel and is not an actual module.

Comment: depending on what file your importing the module in  lets say am in routes and i want to import server.js , it would be require('../server.js');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled babel modules and followed their documentation closely. I had to point `babel-node` directly to the `server.js` file.

`nodemon -w src --exec babel-node src/server.js --presets env,stage-0`